# How to set an if statement to less than and greater than at once on python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input("Enter choice: "))
if a > 3 and a < 1:  #the issue is here how can i rewrite it to allow this?
    print("Invalid choice")
else:
    print("Correct choice")
```

As you can see i'd like it to allow "a" to be less than 1 and greater than 3, but the way I wrote it does not work.

Comment: Just use `or` instead of `and`. Boolean logic for the win!

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Wow that fixed it thanks!

Comment: A number cannot be greater than 3 and less than 1 at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain the conditions in the opposite way:

```
if 1 <= a <= 3:
    print("Correct choice")
else:
    print("Invalid choice")
```

Comment: OP wants to check if a is greater than 3 or less than 1, not if it is between 1 and 3. :)

Comment: Look closer. I don't think you noticed that I've put what's in his if clause into the else clause, and vice versa, effectively achieving exactly what the OP asks for, and arguably making the code more readable.

Comment: I ended going with this, it made it far easier thank you

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong conditional.

To check if *either* condition is satisfied, use `or`:

```
if a > 3 or a < 1:
```

To check if **both** conditions are satisfied (never possible in this case, of course), you use `and`.